# Pasar variables desde JavaScript a PHP

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando pasar el valor de la variable "desde" desde un script JS a PHP y no hay manera. A ver si alguien me echa una mano.

Mi código en HTML es el siguiente:

```
 <form name="Buscador" method="post" action="encabezadostabla.php" target="_blank" id="formulario">                        
        <b>Desde: </b><input type="date" name="desde" id="desde" required><br>                    
        <input name="submit" class="boton" type="submit" value="Buscar" onclick="validarFechas()">
    </form>    

 <script>
        function validarFecha(){            
           var desde = document.getElementById("desde").value;
           var hasta = document.getElementById("hasta").value;   
           desde_js = new Date(desde);
           hasta_js = new Date(hasta);
           dia = desde_js.getDay();              
           
           if (hasta_js < desde_js){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("HASTA debe ser mayor que DESDE");
           }

           if (dia == 1){      //Si es lunes...                  
            desde_js = desde_js.setDate(desde_js.getDate()-1); //Restar 1 día           
            desde_js = new Date(desde_js);
            desde = desde_js.toISOString().split("T")[0];                              
           }
        }     
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo vas a enviar a un archivo procesador PHP?? Si es así, cuando recojas todas las variables tendrían que llegar las del JS.

Ejemplo de código un poco viejo, pero el concepto es el mismo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javascript_to_php() {
    var jsVar1 = "Hello";
    var jsVar2 = "World";
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "?w1=" + jsVar1 + "&w2=" + jsVar2;
}
</script>
 
<?php
// comprobar si tenemos los parametros w1 y w2 en la URL
if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"])) {
    // asignar w1 y w2 a dos variables
    $phpVar1 = $_GET["w1"];
    $phpVar2 = $_GET["w2"];
 
    // mostrar $phpVar1 y $phpVar2
    echo "<p>Parameters: " . $phpVar1 . " " . $phpVar1 . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
}
?>
```

Recuerda que al pasar variables desde JavaScript a PHP o viceversa, no debemos olvidar filtrar y sanitizar siempre todas las variables para evitar posibles agujeros de seguridad.